# Import WordPress content to my website

Tags: import, blog

I have a website just like WordPress which displays blogs. Now I want to import WordPress content to my blog. Is there any **API** available or any other way or **documentation**? Kindly help, I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Yes, there is the WP REST API that you can use to read posts from the other website.

Comment: More to the point, here are [the docs for WordPress's REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). (Note that the API may be extended or modified by plugins or themes, so this documentation represents what WordPress can do out of the box.)